# How should I approach such classification problem where the input is an array of integers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, keras

I am training a model for predicting a number between 0 to 10 in this case. These are the number of roots of a polynomial. The input array for the number of polynomials is the coefficients of that polynomial from $x^n$ to constant. Even though I prepared a balanced dataset in which all number of roots (from 0 to 10) are equally existed, my input is an array of array of integers.

For example:

```
23 43 -545 34 45 -34 234 -434 234 434 -2344334
```

And the output of this is the number of roots of that polynomial (as I said before).

I tried many combinations of layers, but the accuracy never gets higher than 50% percent. By accuracy, I mean the number of correct predictions (I count the biggest probability as the prediction).

My Keras code for modeling:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=degree+1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(degree+1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, batch_size=50, verbose=0)
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Is this a good model for this kind of problem? I am new to deep learing so if the answer is obvious, I am sorry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your information is not discriminative enough**

Why? Coefficients of polynomials dont give (alteast partially) discriminative information about roots of the polynomial. In other words different coefficients could give same roots.

**It does not matter how complex your network is it cant catch what is not there to be catched in the first place.**